# Does this equation have any positive rational solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does the equation

$$8a^{2}b^{2}(8a^{n}b^{n} + 1) = (a^{2} + b^{2})^2$$

have any positive rational solutions where $n\geq 1$ is an integer ?

EDIT 1: The factor $8ab$ was replaced by the more general $8a^{n}b^{n}$, where $n\geq 1$ is an integer.

My attempt: By rewriting the RHS as $4a^{2}b^{2}(16a^{n}b^{n} + 2)$, it seems easier to consider the equation $$y^2 = 16x^{n} + 2$$, where $x$ and $y$ are rational and $n$ is a positive integer. But am still to find any idea to proceed from here.

Comment: Context; where does this problem come from?

Comment: @Winther, i stumbled upon it whilst i was playing around with the Pythagoras equation. From whence i then generalised it to $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Well you should add that to the question (i.e. explain the origin of this in more detail). The reason this is relevant; it this was a book / contest problem then we would know that there is a straight forward way to solve it. If it is thought up then this is not always (rearly) the case. Also showing how you got it will allow people to build on what you have done.

Comment: @Winther, note that the RHS is exactly the RHS of the Pythagoras equation. Then you can simply take the components of the LHS as the other factors of the Pythagoras equation.